# BGE Animated rig freezes when rig goes off-screen... Can I make it not?

Tags: animation, game-engine

I have an animated enemy chasing the player. On the enemy's rig, I save the animation's current frame to a property. I use this property to cue sounds.

It works fine when the player is looking at the enemy. However, when the player turn's their back and the enemy goes out of view, the animation freezes. I can tell that it has frozen because the property I am saving the current frame to stops incrementing. When the player looks back at the enemy, the animation starts from the beginning.

I'm assuming that this is something Blender does intentionally for performance reasons. Can I make it stop?

Comment: Right now, I have found a hackish workaround that involves copying keyframe values from separate empties that just count. I'd rather know a way to have Blender not freeze my rig, though.

Answer (score 0):

Any animation that is not seen by the active camera is culled, this is called `frustum-culling`. As for a solution for it, I am not 100% sure this is a solution, but you can disable frustum culling for a particular camera at run-time with the following code. `KX_Camera.frustum_culling`
Which is layman terms looks something like this.

```
import bge

def main(self):

  self.owner.scene.cameras["Camera_Name"].frustum_culling = False
```

There is also another option called `KX_Scene.activity_culling`. Again, I am not sure exactly if this only applies to object logic, and not also object animation. The code for it can be found below.

```
import bge

def main(self):

  self.owner.scene.activity_culling = False
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Unfortunately, it looks like the animation is culled anyway. My workaround works reasonably, though.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, there are numerous functions to get/set/activate actions at run-time.

```
KX_GameObject.playAction()

KX_GameObject.stopAction()

KX_GameObject.getActionFrame()

KX_GameObject.getActionName()

KX_GameObject.setActionFrame()

KX_GameObject.isPlayingAction()
```

Comment: I did try those, but the animation still freezes outside of the camera's frustum, even if I attempt to set the animation's action frame directly with setActionFrame().

Comment: Unfortunate. I don't think I have any more ideas for a solution. Sorry. :(